# gitlab-ci parent-child include not working

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to include another file with jobs (parent-child) but it's not doing anything:

.gitlab-ci.yml looks like this:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
      variables:
        CODENAME: all
    - when: always

stages:
 - stage1
 - stage2

job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules: 
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - changes: 
      - job1/*
      variables:
        CODENAME: all
  trigger: 
    include: 
    - project: 'project-name'
      file: 'job1/pipeline.yml'

job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - changes: 
      - job2/*
      variables:
        CODENAME: bionic
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'project-name'
        file: 'job2/pipeline.yml'
```

job1/pipeline.yml:

```
include:
  - project: 'project-name'
    file: file.yml

.template: &template
  extends: .kaniko-build # extend of the above include

job1-1:
  <<: *template
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "xenial" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
job1-2:
  <<: *template
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "bionic" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
job1-3:
  <<: *template
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "focal" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
job1-4:
  <<: *template
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "latest" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
```

job2/pipeline.yml:

```
include:
  - project: 'project-name'
    file: 'job1/pipeline.yml'

include:
  - project: 'project-name'
    file: file.yml
    
.template-custom-image1: &template-custom-image1
  extends: .kaniko-build # extend of the above include

custom-image1-1:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "xenial" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
custom-image1-2:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "bionic" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
custom-image1-3:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "focal" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
custom-image1-4:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
  rules: 
    - if: '$CODENAME == "latest" || $CODENAME == "all"'
      when: always
    - when: never
```

Right now changes in job2 folder is triggering job2 which will trigger job2/pipeline.yml, all fine and dandy. But right now I only see one job meaning **custom-image1-x**. I'd expect to also see job1/pipeline.yml job1-x included as I include that in job2/pipeline.yml:

```
include:
  - project: 'project-name'
    file: 'job1/pipeline.yml'
```

I also have the requirement for them to run sequentially, so I can't use another trigger, as they'll run in parallel. Any clues or tipps how to tackle? Maybe I'm looking at this from the wrong angle?

Comment: please help others to help you and create a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry and thank you @SimonSchrottner will edit this out!

Comment: Updated @SimonSchrottner Hope it's better understandable this way. Sorry for the overcomplicated example in the first place!

Comment: is everything within the same project?

Comment: and i am not sure, why you want to redo the same build, as it is part of stage1 already

Comment: Everything in the same project.
It's complicated, I tried to min. complexity as you asked and removed the rules that inherit vars to make the point of my question more obvious but I'm going to re-add the vars so it makes sense.
 
I have 2 use cases:
1. I need to be able to run jobs in stage1 and stage2 individually but in a sequential order beginning with stage1 then stage2. A change in the repo in stage2 should trigger stage1 jobs with the same vars defined.
2. I need to be able to run all stages and all jobs defined sequentially in a daily scheduled run.

Comment: I've added the rules again, so you have an idea. But basically depending on whether the pipeline is a scheduled or not it will set a variable (codename: all). In turn that will trigger all the jobs because all have codename: all. This way I make sure that all jobs will run. With one caveat which is that with the include of job1/pipeline.yml jobs these would run twice.
Either way second use case is also covered. If not scheduled pipeline it will check for changes on the repo and trigger the codename: whatever jobs and nothing else. And that should run sequentially stage1 then stage2 etc.

Comment: I've found another caveat which is that stages in gitlab-ci won't run sequentially because they are triggers, so they'll execute in parallel. I guess I could use needs there but let's focus on the main issue because that is definitely why I started to include the job1/pipeline.yml into stage2 :-/

Comment: Can you be more specific about the requirements? Which things must run sequentially specifically? For the trigger/parallelization issue, Have you tried setting the [trigger strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#triggerstrategy) to `depend`? Or do you mean you need the separate pipelines to run in sequence with each other?

Comment: I have not looked into depend (/facepalm) 

OK I try:

if it's a scheduled job (daily sync). then codename var is all so stage1 should run then stage2 in sequential order including all jobs of their respective triggered child pipeline. (depend should solve that).

Comment: maybe also this is an approach which might be easier, and also solve your problem https://gitlab.com/aepfli/lema-setup - it is not 100%  your case, and maybe the setup needs refinement with an additional variable - but it can work

Comment: Thank you @SimonSchrottner :-O will have a look into your approach! Much appreciated! :-)

Comment: I just tried this @SimonSchrottner but there's one problem: 
If I change the first rule in job setup from - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule" to:     - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" I can manually trigger the pipeline but right now it's saying there are no jobs. and I guess that's because "all" is not defined in the .matrix extends. Basically a manual trigger should execute them all. :-/

Comment: Well either you add a rule for that, or you add a variable during the manual trigger and uncomment the lines I added ;) - but I think it is a cleaner and easier to understand approach

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand how this will have an effect on all jobs being run. :-/
Just to clarify, if the variable codename is "all", all jobs (xenial, bionic, focal & latest) in stage1 and stage2 should run.
I'm still getting the same error: "No stages / jobs for this pipeline." :-/

Comment: any chance @SimonSchrottner if you could point me to some sort of explanation how "codename: all" could fill up the matrix so that 4 jobs would be created for each stage? Thank you!

Comment: It is based on the two conditions in the rule... As soon as one condition evaluates to true, they will be used. So it checks if the codename is the build codename, which evaluates to false in the case of all - on the next rule it evaluates if the codename is all and therefore the job will be used. Maybe I messed up variable names, need to check

Comment: @SimonSchrottner Yes configuring "all" as codename will trigger the extends in the stage BUT my .kaniko-build is not an echo but another templated job that builds images according to the codename variable. If it's not specified there's nothing to do. In theory it would create bionic, focal, latest or xenial ubuntu images but it needs to be specified with the codename var. I could rewrite the kaniko-build extends but that is a general template that we use we rather not change. see "custom-image1-1" above for an example how I created logic in my pipeline to cover it.

Comment: @SimonSchrottner I've spent more time on your example and with the current configuration no stages run. The syntax is correct but when you simulate the job it just doesn't do anything. Reason for that I believe is that .pre stage only applies if stage1 and stage2 rules apply, and they aren't. Because CODENAME is not set so it won't create any jobs/stages for those 2 stages and therefor not run .pre stage. Can work around that problem if you change the rules in the stages (if: $codename) and define a workflow rule on top that sets codename.

Comment: the misconception I believe tho in this request here is that I always run 4 jobs. If the var codename is "all", then yes 4 jobs and the parallelization should run. But if the var codename for example is bionic, it should only create 1 job for each stage with bionic. So in theory depending on whether there were changes in job1/* I need to extend or not extend the matrix, if that makes sense?

Comment: yes I could work around that with adding another var as you've pointed out but I have some 40 stages so including/excluding them is going to be a major pain for anyone that wants to change something.

Comment: i am not  sure what you mean with 40 stages and excludes - it is quiet hard to also help you with little to no code, and what you have tried :) so maybe you can point me to an url or something, where i can inspect, or write comments to code or something

Comment: Thank you @SimonSchrottner for all your help! I've found a solution. I'll post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my main issue was that I needed to run stage1 additionally when there are changes in stage2. I've fixed this with adding workflow rules with changes to stage2 (job2/*):

previously I had in my .gitlab-ci in job2:

```
job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - changes: 
      - job2/*
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'project-name'
        file: 'job2/pipeline.yml'
```

which would trigger job2/pipeline.yml:

```
include:
  - project: 'project-name'
    file: 'job1/pipeline.yml'

include:
  - project: 'project-name'
    file: file.yml
    
.template-custom-image1: &template-custom-image1
  extends: .kaniko-build # extend of the above include

custom-image1-1:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
custom-image1-2:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
custom-image1-3:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
custom-image1-4:
  <<: *template-custom-image1
```

On top you notice an include for job1/pipeline.yml

```
include:
  - project: 'project-name'
    file: 'job1/pipeline.yml'
```

Which I somehow expected to magically execute - without an extend or anything but it never executed. I fixed this like this in .gitlab-ci:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - changes: 
      - job2/*
      variables: 
        SET_STAGE: TWO
        CODENAME: bionic
...

job1:
  stage: stage1
  rules:
    - if: $SET_STAGE == "TWO"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - changes: 
      - job1/*
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'project-name'
        file: 'job1/pipeline.yml'
    strategy: depend

job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "master" && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - changes: 
      - job2/*
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: 'project-name'
        file: 'job2/pipeline.yml'
    strategy: depend
```

So really all I did is on top in my .gitlab-ci I defined workflow rules that would set a variable (SET_STAGE) on changes in job2/* and use that variable in my first stage. If it's set than it will run that stage as well. Of course I could have solved it this way:

```
...
    - changes: 
      - job1/*
    - changes: 
      - job2/*
...
```

instead of this:

```
...
    - changes: 
      - job1/*
    - if: $SET_STAGE == "TWO"
...
```

But I needed to set an overall common variable (CODENAME) somewhere anyway which I'm doing in workflows and moved that into separate file, thus making my .gitlab-ci file a bit slimmer.

It looks really simple but it took me a while to figure that out. The Matrix mentioned by Simon in the first post comments is interesting but for my use-case not really useful. So I kept it the way it is and that's working fine. Another issue I solved within this thread was with "strategy: depend" so stage1 and stage2 would not execute in parallel. Thanks everyone for helping! :-)

Answer (score 0):

secondly:
changes in job1/* should only trigger stage1's specific job in child pipeline. changes in job2/* however should trigger stage1 and then stage2 sequentially (depends) but with the variable defined in .gitlab-ci:

```
job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - changes: 
      - job2/*
      variables:
        CODENAME: bionic
```

Sorry had to post this as an answer so it's properly formatted :-/